# Inserir em loop sem repetir dados NodeJS + mysql?

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursão

Preciso inserir o campo DESCRICAO em uma tabela CATEGORIA;

Estou com meus dados em formato JSON (já no servidor);

O meu loop roda a sequencia de passos:

1. Verifica se o campo "categoria" existe no objeto JSON
2. Realiza SELECT para ver se o dado já existe no banco de dados

   `SELECT * FROM CATEGORIA WHERE DESCRICAO = '${categoria}' ORDER BY ID_CATEGORIA ASC LIMIT 1`
3. SE o resultset retornou algo ele pega o 1° ID_CATEGORIA encontrado, SE NÃO ele insere a categoria no banco

   `INSERT INTO categoria(descricao) VALUES ('${categoria}')`
4. Volta ao passo 1 até acabar os objetos JSON

O problema é que quando eu insiro um JSON o loop roda completamente (isto é, todos os objetos), inclusive o SELECT funciona normalmente 1 por 1, mas somente depois de o loop finalizado ele executa as queries de INSERT.

Quando insiro o próximo JSON que já tem CATEGORIA cadastrada ele não realiza os INSERT, mas armazena o meu ID_CATEGORIA em uma variável como esperado, normalmente.

**Não posso inserir categorias repetidas no banco**, essa é uma das situações que uso recursividade, porém usarei também para outras como CIDADE, que também não pode ter repetida...

Já tentei diversas estruturas de loop, ex: for, for...of, forEach(), e libs como sync-each, sync, e mais algumas, mas **todas só inserem os dados depois do loop finalizado (mesmo que a query insert está dentro do loop)**.

OBS: Estou usando as lib querystring e mysql dentro de um servidor HTTP

```
req.on('data', function (data) {
                objJson = JSON.parse(data)

                popularDados(0);

                // Função recursiva para inserir dados no banco
                function popularDados(x) {
                    if (x < objJson.objetos.length) {

                        // Populando categoria
                        processarCategoria(objJson.objetos[x]);

                        function processarCategoria(atualObjeto) {[...]}

                        popularDados(x + 1)
                     }
                };

})
```

**ATUALIZAÇÃO 04/09/2018**

Solucionei meu problema por momento, passei a função para o front e agora faço X post via ajax, onde x é o número de objetos do meu JSON:

cliente-side:

```
function popularDados(x) {
        if (x < objetos.length) {

            var sendObject = objetos[x];

            $.ajax({
              url: "server.js",
              method: "POST",
              dataType: "Json",
              data: JSON.stringify({
                  objeto : sendObject
              })
            })
              .done(function( obj ) {

                // Usando setTimeout() apenas para visualizar no console
                setTimeout(function(){

                    popularDados(x + 1);

                }, 400);

            })
              .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
                alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
            });          
        }
}
```

server-side:

```
req.on('data', function (data) {

        objJson = JSON.parse(data)

        // Visualizando o dado da chave "categoria" no console
        console.log('\nCategoria : ' + objJson.objeto.categoria)


        processarCategoria(objJson.objeto);

        function processarCategoria(atualObjeto) {[...]}

    })
```

Comment: Boa tarde. A querystring, você criou uma promesa (promise) para ela?

Comment: Boa Tarde, não criei, cheguei a ler esses dois artigos:
[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Usando_promises)

Porém não consegui adaptar no meu código :/
Você poderia me ajudar com  o entendimento e criação dela?

Comment: Criei um gits para demonstrar como fica usando a query com promise, vê se você consegue entender . [PROMISE](https://gist.github.com/andersonmendesdev/a3b9e231d71049ea1727341905ae25d5)
O uso de promise para query de banco de dados é importante, pois, o nodejs é assíncrono e chamadas a bancos sempre ficam por ultimo na execução do cogido, ele faz isso pois sabe q as chamadas consomem um tempo a mais na execução. E gerando a promesa você obriga o node a realizar a inserção nao ordem que você definir.

Comment: Neste exemplo também fiz uso de de async/await, separei a promesa em uma função e depois tornei a segunda função async e fiz a execução aguardar o retorno da promesa (await). Desta forma o ultimo conselo.log nao sera undefined.

Comment: Agradeço seu apoio @AndersonMendes , porém esta solução, assim como as outras que já tentei e a que está implementada (referente ao SELECT) funcionam perfeitamente, mas ao fazer uma query INSERT ela não respeitou a promisse, assim como as outras tentativas realizou o INSERT no fim.. :/

Comment: Humm entendo, vou realizar alguns teste com algo parecido que você tem e depois aviso o resultado.

Comment: @AndersonMendes , resolvi o problema que eu estava, migrei a função recursiva para o front, fiz ela com o objeto ainda no front enviando 1 objeto por vez, ou seja, 1 post ajax por vez, e BAZINGA!! Não insere mais dados repetidos...
 Agradeço de verdade pela sua ajuda, agora entendo promise! Abraço :)

Comment: Opa que bom, pior que eu não realizei o test com recursividade e promise, mas irei, quero saber o comportamento das promises com recursão.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESPONDENDO COM ATUALIZAÇÃO DE 04/09/2018 PARA DEIXAR QUESTÃO COMO SOLUCIONADA**

Solucionei meu problema por momento, passei a função para o front e agora faço X post via ajax, onde x é o número de objetos do meu JSON:

client-side:

```
function popularDados(x) {
    if (x < objetos.length) {

        var sendObject = objetos[x];

        $.ajax({
          url: "server.js",
          method: "POST",
          dataType: "Json",
          data: JSON.stringify({
              objeto : sendObject
          })
        })
          .done(function( obj ) {

            // Usando setTimeout() apenas para visualizar no console
            setTimeout(function(){

                popularDados(x + 1);

            }, 400);

        })
          .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        });          
    }
}
```

server-side:

```
req.on('data', function (data) {

    objJson = JSON.parse(data)

    // Visualizando o dado da chave "categoria" no console
    console.log('\nCategoria : ' + objJson.objeto.categoria)


    processarCategoria(objJson.objeto);

    function processarCategoria(atualObjeto) {[...]}

})
```

Repositório do projeto: https://github.com/JhowRaul/Imobiliaria-BI